# jquery/javascript input checkbox checked attribute (readonly not working)

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

Why is the checked attribute not visible in the DOM?

In the `onchange` `input.val()` is always `on`, but the `checked` attribute is changing??

```
input.change(_=> {
    console.log('val:', input.val(), ', checked:', input.prop('checked'));
});
```

console

```
val: on , checked: true
val: on , checked: false
val: on , checked: true
val: on , checked: false
```

## readonly not working

If the input checkbox is `readonly` I can still change the value and when clicking the checkbox gives the same output in console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `value` of a radio or checkbox element doesn't change (unless you do it programmatically, but we're talking about simple user interaction with the form here).

When you check the radio/checkbox only the `checked` property changes. It's this property which should determine what action you take when your user interacts with the form.

> Why is the checked attribute not visible in the DOM?

This is because it's the `checked` *property* of the Element object which is being updated, not the `checked` attribute. If you want to update the DOM change `prop()` to `attr()` in you JS code, but note that this is slower and serves no useful purpose in this case.

There is a very good answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6004028/519413) which goes in to detail on the difference between properties and attributes in JavaScript, which may help to clear up any confusion.